# How to understand this simple example of thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

it is an example about `wait()` and `notify()` in Java Concurrency. My theory knowledge about it doesn't explain me about this code and I cannot explain why this gives me a misunderstood result.

So, This is code to get an idea:

```
public class ExampleOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test b = new Test();
        b.start();
        synchronized(b){
           try{    
              b.wait();
           } catch(InterruptedException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
           }
           System.out.println(b.total);
        }
    }
}

class Test extends Thread {
    int total;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i =0;i<50;i++){
                total+=i;
                System.out.println("I am here");
            }
            notify();
        }
    } 
}
```

The result is : `4950`

So, how to understand this process (how `total` can be 4950)?

I understand that If I call `wait()` it stops the object's thread which called this method and woken up it then another thread calls `notify()`. Also, `synchronized()` block restricts threads and accept only one thread in one time.

- So when thread calls notify(), it becomes non-active until other
  thread calls wait()?
- How wait() and notify() play it's role in this code? Also `synchronized()` block?
- So, how  many threads are created in this code?

I am confused about this. Help me to figure it out.

Comment: `wait()` on object puts the calling thread into a waiting state, until `notify()` or `notifyAll()` is called on the same object. It's not the object's thread. It's the thread, that acquires a lock on the object, and calls `wait()` on it.

Comment: Beware of this code: if `Test` thread calls `notify()` before the main thread calls `wait()`, main thread will wait forever. I suggest you move `b.start` **inside** `synchronized(b)` to avoid this potential problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I call wait() it stops the object's thread which called this method and woken up it then another thread calls notify()

Right.  `notify()` *or* `notifyAll()` on the *same* object instance will awaken the thread.

> So when thread calls notify(), it becomes non-active until other thread calls wait()?

No.  Notify just signals a thread that is waiting on the same object.  The thread that calls `notify()` continues running and does not release the `synchronized` lock that it is holding.

> How wait() and notify() play it's role in this code?

Without wait/notify. the main thread would not wait for the calculation to finish so would probably print 0.

> Also synchronized() block?

When you use `wait()` or `notify()` you need to be in a `synchronized` block.  It is the monitor associated with the object instance that you are `synchronized` on that is being waited on and being notified.  Also, the `synchronized` block ensures memory synchronization so the main threads *sees* the changes to the `notify` field.  Each thread has a memory cache and there needs to be mechanisms in place for threads to publish their changes and see changes to fields made by other threads.

> So, how many threads are created in this code?

1 thread is created by your code and the main thread is created automagically by the JVM.

It is important to realize that there is a race condition in this code.  It is possible for the new thread to start up, spin through the loop, call notify and exit *before* the main thread actually calls `wait`.  This is unlikely because starting a thread takes some time but it could happen.  In that case, the main thread would be stuck in `wait` forever because there is no one there to notify it.

Couple other comments:

- I recommended that you use `this.notify()`.  It's always good to reiterate what is being `notified`.
- As  @JBNizet points out, it is better to use a `private final` lock object as opposed to a `Thread` object.
- It is always recommended to define a class that `implements Runnable` as opposed to extending thread.  Then you would  do `new Thread(new TestRunnable()); ...`.

Comment: It'd call it just once, but would stay in a waiting state forever.

Comment: "In that case, the main thread would call wait forever" - seemed as an endless loop to me.

Comment: so, there are 2 threads: Test object and main() method. So then b.waits(), main thread goes to run() and execute the loop. After this it calls notify() to wake up Test() object thread. But I do not get it, how can class field 'total' become to 4950?

Comment: When the main thread calls `b.wait()` it stops running until the `Test` thread calls `notify` -- it does not call the loop.  When the new `Test` thread is started, that's when its `run()` method is called in parallel with the main thread.  It is the new `Test` thread which calls the loop which takes `total to 4950.  See @JB's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Gray's excellent answer, here's what happens:

main thread:

```
---------------------------------------------------->
|                   |                            |
start Test thread   waits until notified         wakes up and prints the result
```

Test thread:

```
                         ------------------------>
                         |                     |
                         starts running        notifies main thread
                         computes the sum
```

Also note that it's generally considered bad practice to call `wait()` and `notify()` on a Thread instance. A shared object, acting as a lock, should be used instead. `notifyAll()` should be preferred generally, or even better, a higher-level abstraction like a CountDownLatch should used.